# I want, How to read dlt binary File without dlt viwer, using c++ fstream

Tags: c++, parsing, logging

I want to make simple console program.
the program is dead checking program
Sometimes the point of death on the log is different from where it actually happened.
The format of the dlt file is as follows.
I want to parse the following binary files through c ++.
I tried many times to read the binary file but it failed.
I would appreciate it if you could upload a simple example source.\
Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <io.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct dltLogFormat
{
char dltPattern[100];
unsigned int TimeStamp_sec;
int TimeStamp_mic;
char ECU_ID[4];
};

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
vector<string> dltList;
char dltPattern[5] = "";
unsigned int TimeStamp_sec = 0;
int TimeStamp_mic = 0;
char ECU_ID_CHARACTER[5] = "";
char infoHeader;
unsigned short messageLength;
int ECU_ID = 0;
unsigned int sessionID = 0;
int extHeaderInfo = 0;
unsigned int numberOfArguments = 0;
unsigned int applicationID = 0;
unsigned int ContextID = 0;
char payload[17];

_finddata_t fd;
long handle;
int result = 1;
handle = _findfirst(".\\*.dlt", &fd);

if (handle == -1)
{
    printf("There were no dlt files.\n");
    return;
}

while (result != -1)
{
    dltLogFormat dltFormant;
    dltList.push_back(fd.name);
    printf("File: %s\n", fd.name);
    result = _findnext(handle, &fd);

    std::ifstream input(fd.name, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

    while (true)
    {
        input >> dltPattern;
        input.read((char*)&TimeStamp_sec, sizeof(unsigned int));
        input.read((char*)&TimeStamp_mic, sizeof(int));
        input >> ECU_ID_CHARACTER;
        input.read((char*)&infoHeader, sizeof(char));
        input.read((char*)&messageLength, sizeof(unsigned short));
        input.read((char*)&ECU_ID, sizeof(int));
        input.read((char*)&sessionID, sizeof(unsigned int));
        input.read((char*)&extHeaderInfo, sizeof(unsigned int));
        input.read((char*)&numberOfArguments, sizeof(unsigned int));
        input.read((char*)&applicationID, sizeof(unsigned int));
        input.read((char*)&ContextID, sizeof(unsigned int));
        input.read(payload, sizeof(char)*messageLength);
        //header

        //input

        //extend header


        //payload
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This site is called StackOverflow, not RentACoder.

Comment: sorry,added my code and i want payload section read

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: _"I tried many times to read the binary file but it failed"_ is not a very useful problem report. What did you see? What did you expect?